# How to create another instance of your class by using the parameterized constructor

Tags: constructor

6. Testing your program

Create a class called Demo.java. This class will contain your main method

Create an instance of your class (an object) by using the default constructor.

Call all your objects setter (mutator) methods to assign values to your object

Call the objects display method, to print out it's values

Create another instance of your class (another object) by using the parameterized constructor

Call the objects display method, to print out it's values

```
public class Shoes {


//Instance Variables
private String brand; 
private int cost; 
private double size; 


// Default Constructor
    public Shoes(){
        brand = "";
        cost = 0;
        size = 0;
    }

//Constructor
public Shoes (String brand, int cost, double size)
{
    this.brand = brand;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.size = size;
}



//Setter
public void setBrand (String brand)
{
    this.brand=brand;
}

public void setCost (int cost)
{
    this.cost=cost;
}

public void setSize (double size)
{
    this.size=size;
}


//Getter
public String getBrand()
{
    return brand;
}

public int getCost()
{
    return cost;
}

public double getSize()
{
    return size;
}

// Display data
public void display()
{
    System.out.println(brand);
    System.out.println(cost);
    System.out.println(size);

}
```

}

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a object
            Shoes yeezys = new Shoes();
            Shoes kobes = new Shoes();

            yeezys.setBrand("Adidas");
            yeezys.setCost(200);
            yeezys.setSize(8.5);
            yeezys.display();

        System.out.println(""); 

    //Second object? Need help with this
            kobes.setBrand("Nike");
            kobes.setCost(150);
            kobes.setSize(9.5);
            kobes.display();

}
```

}

Comment: Hopes this object creation tutorial  link helps[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)